# Idiomatic usage of ‘über’ vs ‘an’ when thinking

Tags: word-usage, preposition, idiomaticity

I recently started a Duolingo tree, and for prepositions they used the sentence

> Ich denke an dich.

rather than

> Ich denke über dich.

Prior to this point, I would have used über without thinking twice; so I was just wondering if there is an idiomatic difference between the two? Is one more personal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is pretty simple: One is correct and one is wrong.

It is correct to use *an:*

> Ich denke *an* dich.
>   Ich denke *an* meine Zukunft.

*Denken* itself does not allow an argument with *über.* You may be confusing this with the related verb *nachdenken.* *Nachdenken* takes an argument connected with *über* and only that.

> Ich denke *über* dich *nach.*
>   Ich denke *über* meine Zukunft *nach.*

The meanings of the two are different. *Über etwas/jemanden nachdenken* means to reflect about something, to engage in rather complex thoughts, while *an etwas/jemanden denken* is more along the lines of to remember, to wish someone were here.

---

This may seem confusing as with so many things in languages that basically evolved to be that way without much design behind it. But it kind of makes sense. If you are *thinking of* somebody/something then you can imagine yourself placing your thoughts next to (*an*) that something. If you are reflecting *about* something, you can imagine your thoughts circling *over* that something much like vultures. But again, these images are completely arbitrary as any other set of images would be. Bottom line is: These prepositions are correct, others are not.